# Parsing JSON using QJSON

Tags: qt, qt4, qjson

My json output look like [{"id":2,"name":"AAA"},{"id":1,"name":"BBB"}]. I want to parse this using Qjson in mac. I am trying to parsing but I could not get any outputs . please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you some errors? Regarding your Json chain it's an array with 2 objects in it. Format seems to be ok. Please provide the your code in order us to see what your are doing

Comment: I am using the following code,
QJson::Parser parser;
bool ok;
QVariantMap result = parser.parse (cityReply->readAll(), &ok).toMap();
if (!ok) {
qFatal("An error occurred during parsing");
exit (1);
}
qDebug() << "Name :" << result.value("name").toString();

}
the output is : Name : "" 

Note : if I displays cityReply->readAll() in messagebox then I can view the webservice result (json String).

Comment: I am using the following code,                               QJson::Parser parser;                                                  bool ok;                                                      QVariantMap result=parser.parse (cityReply->readAll(),&ok).toMap();                                                      if (!ok) { qFatal("An error occurred during parsing"); exit (1); } qDebug() << "Name :" << result.value("name").toString(); } the output is : Name : "" Note : if I displays cityReply->readAll() in messagebox then I can view the webservice result (json String).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the issue is quite simple, the JSON representation implies an Array of records.
You are trying to access the record without using an iterator or a loop.

Use the snippet below to transform the QVariant into a list

```
QVariantList result = parser.parse(cityReply->readAll(), &ok).toList();
```

And then loop against records for example:

```
foreach(QVariant record, result) {
    QVariantMap map = record.toMap();
    qDebug() << map.value("name");
}
```

Comment: I am getting the empty list. :(

Comment: Try this: QVariant result = parser.parse(cityReply->readAll(), &ok); qDebug() << result; Do you have any output in the console?

Comment: I am getting the following output QVariant(, ).

Comment: I just made a test and it is outputting QVariant(QString, "AAA") 
QVariant(QString, "BBB")... I think the QJson lib is not correctly installed on your system.

Comment: hi.. I got the paring data. just made one change in the code. using the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732998/qjson-using-in-mac-getting-some-issues